# Google Chrome Flag Confusion

Tags: google-chrome

I want to disable security in Android Chrome. On search i come across we can disable security for normal Windows Chrome using the parameter - "chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="[some directory here]""

However when i search how to do it for Android Chrome. I come across chrome://flags option

I have opened and add the addrees in "insecure origins treated as secure" enabled.

But still facing CORS issue

Please advise.